# How to make autocomplete search box using jquery ui

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using jquery UI for autocomplete in the search box.

So this is the array I'm passing from the controller to the view which contains the JS.

```
public function suggest_channel(){
        $this->load->library('mcurl');
        $arr_channel_title = array();
        $arr_main = array();
        if($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
            $keyword = $_POST['channel_url'];
            $str_search_url = $this->youtube_api_url . "search";
            $arr_search_params
             = array(
                'part'   => 'snippet',
                'q'      => $keyword,
                'fields' => 'items',
                'type'   => 'channel',
                'key'    => $this->youtube_api_key,
                'maxResults' => 10
            );
            $this->mcurl->add_call(null, 'get', $str_search_url, $arr_search_params);
            $yt_api_data = $this->mcurl->execute();
            $arr_response = json_decode($yt_api_data[0]['response'], TRUE);

            foreach ($arr_response['items'] as $items) {
                $arr_main[$x]['id'] = $items['snippet']['channelId'];
                $arr_main[$x]['label'] = $items['snippet']['channelTitle'];
                $arr_main[$x]['img_url'] = $items['snippet']['thumbnails']['default']['url'];
                $x++;
            }

            echo json_encode($arr_main);
        }       
    }
```

This returns something like this

```
[{

    "id":"UCt4t-jeY85JegMlZ-E5UWtA",
    "channel_name":"aajtaktv",
    "img_url":"https:\/\/yt3.ggpht.com\/-ZE5JmiUBlGo \/AAAAAAAAAAI\/AAAAAAAAAAA\/JU-NHnMeaY8\/s512-c-k-no\/photo.jpg"

},
{

    "id":"UCyyP7tUlQYhYCDmqafg7Rpg",
    "channel_name":"DilliAajtak",
    "img_url":"https:\/\/yt3.ggpht.com\/-V41A_NRHePA\/AAAAAAAAAAI\/AAAAAAAAAAA\/W13cwzn8Xws \/s512-c-k-no\/photo.jpg"

},
{

    "id":"UCKeZdjO26bvvLOQ68-nAFhQ",
    "channel_name":"AajTakAstro",
    "img_url":"https :\/\/yt3.ggpht.com\/-mNkTltsXomk\/AAAAAAAAAAI\/AAAAAAAAAAA\/sFXYX5AIgnU\/s512-c-k-no\/photo.jpg"

}]
```

This is the data which should be shown in the textbox when user types 'aaj' in the textbox.

Now I'm trying to display this data in the search box when a user enters a keyword like this

```
$("#channel_url").keyup(function() {
        var str_user_entered_channel_url=  $("#channel_url").val();
        if(str_user_entered_channel_url.length >= 2){
            if(str_user_entered_channel_url != ''){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?=base_url()?>chtool/suggest_channel",
                    data: {"channel_url" : str_user_entered_channel_url},
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function(response) {
                        $("#channel_url").autocomplete({
                            source: response
                        });
                    }
                });         
            }
        }       
    });
```

But I'm not getting any suggestions from the autocomplete. I need this data to show in the textbox. Can anyone help?

Comment: I think you're using it ina manner that is not going to work this way. Have you reviewed the JQuery UI Demos for this type of application?

Comment: Yes I checked their demo here https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ and they are directly using the response there. So, I'm not sure what is my situation how can I do that in my case.

Comment: Your `response` is much more complex than the demo. Look here: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote This is the demo you should try to emulate.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your Source Data, it's too complex for Autocomplete. It should be a simple Array of options. I have setup a small test: https://jsfiddle.net/ydL6vku7/

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <label>Channel:</label>
  <input type="text" id="channel_url" />
</div>
<div id="results">
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
var response = [{
  "id": "UCt4t-jeY85JegMlZ-E5UWtA",
  "channel_name": "aajtaktv",
  "img_url": "https:\/\/yt3.ggpht.com\/-ZE5JmiUBlGo \/AAAAAAAAAAI\/AAAAAAAAAAA\/JU-NHnMeaY8\/s512-c-k-no\/photo.jpg"
}, {
  "id": "UCyyP7tUlQYhYCDmqafg7Rpg",
  "channel_name": "DilliAajtak",
  "img_url": "https:\/\/yt3.ggpht.com\/-V41A_NRHePA\/AAAAAAAAAAI\/AAAAAAAAAAA\/W13cwzn8Xws \/s512-c-k-no\/photo.jpg"
}, {
  "id": "UCKeZdjO26bvvLOQ68-nAFhQ",
  "channel_name": "AajTakAstro",
  "img_url": "https :\/\/yt3.ggpht.com\/-mNkTltsXomk\/AAAAAAAAAAI\/AAAAAAAAAAA\/sFXYX5AIgnU\/s512-c-k-no\/photo.jpg"
}];

$(function() {
  var channel_names = [];
  $.each(response, function(k, v) {
    channel_names[k] = v.channel_name;
  });
  console.log(channel_names);
  $("#channel_url").autocomplete({
    source: channel_names,
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        if (ui.item.value == response[i].channel_name) {
          $("#results").html("<p>ID: " + response[i].id + "</p><img src='" + response[i].channel_name + "' /><p>" + response[i].channel_name + "</p>");
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

This works as expected, once we have created an array to use. Now we need to make it work with remote data. That will be more challenging. It would be best to do a short `GET` to get all the `channel_names` up front. Then when one is selected, get that selections object data specifically. So we will change the `source` to a `function(request, response){}` as described by the [Multiple, Remote Demo](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple-remote). This is where we will perform the AJAX. It will look something like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#channel_url").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "<?=base_url()?>chtool/suggest_channel",
        data: {
          "channel_name": request,
          "type": "array"
        },
        type: "POST",
        success: response
      });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "<?=base_url()?>chtool/suggest_channel",
        data: {
          "channel_name": ui.item.value,
          "type": "object"
        },
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
          $("#results").html("<p>ID: " + data.id + "</p><img src=" + data.img_url + " /><p>" + data.channel_name + "</p>");
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

And you can adjust your PHP like so:

```
if($_POST['type'] == "object"){
    foreach ($arr_response['items'] as $items) {
        $arr_main[$x]['id'] = $items['snippet']['channelId'];
        $arr_main[$x]['channel_name'] = $items['snippet']['channelTitle'];
        $arr_main[$x]['img_url'] = $items['snippet']['thumbnails']['default']['url'];
        $x++;
    }
    echo json_encode($arr_main);
} elseif($_POST['type'] == "array"){
    $arr_channel_names = [];
    foreach ($arr_response['items'] as $items) {
        array_push($arr_channel_names, $items['snippet']['channelTitle']);
    }
    echo json_encode($arr_channel_names);
}
```

I could not test the AJAX, so the second half is untested. I hope this helps.

**EDIT**

I was able to mimic the AJAX activity here: https://jsfiddle.net/ydL6vku7/5/

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and effort to help me really thankful for that. I tried doing it the way you suggested but as you can see the keyup function I used is passing the values in the text box which is received in the controller. So added this parameter to the solution you suggested but it returns me the wrong data from the API also it doesn't shows the auto complete and throws an error - "TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a" this error shows for jquery.js ...pe&&b?!0:"array"===c||0===b||"number"==typeof b&&b>0&&b-1 in a}var s=function(a)...

Comment: @AkashKumar You should not have to use `.keyup()`, that is the whole point of the AutoComplete feature. Using the `source` like I advised would pass the `request` to your PHP, and the `response` would then be populated with an array of possible options the user could select. When they make a selection, then get the object data from your PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the data into a from that is digestable to jQuery-ui autocomplete widget, which is documented [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source). To load data using ajax, you should pass a function as the value of `source` option. This function receives is the value that the user typed in textbox as the `term` property of first argument. So you don't have to handle events such as `keyup` by yourself.

For your length validation, you can use the [`minLength`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-minLength) option, again you don't have to handle it yourself.

Below example shows how to do this in client side.

Here's a [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9qopavbz/).

```js
$("#channel_url").autocomplete({
  minLength:2,
  source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "<?=base_url()?>chtool/suggest_channel",
      data: {
        channel_url: request.term
      },
      type: "POST",
      success: function(resp) {
        response($.map(resp, function(item) {
          //---------^ converts the data structure
          return {
            label: item.channel_name,
            value: item.id
          }
        }));
      }
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="channel_url" />
```

Answer (score 0):

@Twisty and @TJ Thank you guys a lot for helping me. 
This is how I finally was able to do it.

```
$("#channel_url").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, respond) {
            $.post("<?=base_url()?>chtool/suggest_channel", { "channel_url": request.term }, function(response) {
                respond(jQuery.parseJSON(response));
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(event, int_ui) {
            if (int_ui.item.id != null) {
                fetchChannel(0,0,int_ui.item.id);
            } else if (int_ui.item.value != null){
                fetchChannel(0,0,int_ui.item.value);
            }
            else {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('#channel_url').val('');
            }               
        }                       
    });
```

Anything I try except this is not working either or giving me different errors. Can anyone tell me how I can customize this to display an image, also the image url is being sent with the array object check above. Can anyone help me with the this code how I can customize this.

Comment: Although I'm not really sure how can I display the image I'm sending in the array 'img_url' adjacent to the value that is being shown in the autocomplete this way.